# How to use angular filter search on object properties where property's values are formatted with signs like $ or units like V, Amp, in the view?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-filters

I have an array of object containing models where value of model properties are formatted with currency symbols and units like Rs., V, Amp in the view.

```js
var app = angular
  .module('myApp', [])
  .controller('SearchListController', [
    '$scope',
    function($scope) {
      $scope.models = [];

      for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        var model = {
          name: 'Model ' + (i + 1),
          voltage: (i + 1) * 10,
          current: (i + 1) * 20,
          price: (i + 1) * 30.12
        };

        $scope.models.push(model);
      }


    }
  ]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">

  <div ng-controller="SearchListController">

    <input type="text" name="searchModel" ng-model="searchModel" style="width: 80%">
    <div ng-repeat="model in models | filter: searchModel">
      <div>{{$index+1}}. {{model.name}}, {{model.voltage}} V, {{model.current}} Amp, {{model.price | currency : 'Rs.'}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Since angular filter works on object properties, adding units or currency symbol in the search doesn't filter the list. How can I search list of models like `10 V`, or `Rs.30`?

One way is to add an additional property, like database indexing feature, which is a concatenation of all formatted property values. But I'm showing this list of models where one model can be selected. In that case, I'll have to make a copy of the selected model, delete this additional property and then use it.

Please let me know if there are some angular ways to solve this.

Comment: You can try creating custom filter which will honor the signs or units in the filter string and accordingly search in the correct attribute.

Comment: @Maverick Can you please provide some sample code?

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate the units of values in the model itself as I mentioned below.

```
var model = {
      name: 'Model ' + (i + 1),
      voltage: (i + 1) * 10 +'V',
      current: (i + 1) * 20 +'Amp',
      price: 'Rs.'+(i + 1) * 30.12 
    };
```

Remove your Units from the template.

```html
      <div>{{$index+1}}. {{model.name}}, {{model.voltage}}, {{model.current}}, {{model.price}}        
</div>
```

Comment: I can't do that because I'm displaying the list of models in a select list where one model gets selected, selected model is then used in mathematical calculation of division and multiplication.